# Handle button click with two different handler in different condition - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to handle the click of my custom button component in two separate conditions.
This is the `custom-button` component:

```
function CustomButton({status, onStop, onClick}) {

    return (
        // ... 
        <button onClick={status ? onStop : onClick}/>
        // ... 
    )
}
```

This code is just a simple example to explain my question. and I can't separate my component according to the value of `status`.

My question is, Is this an anti-pattern or bad practice in a component? If yes, what's the best practice to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an anti-pattern and more like a bad practice, such code isn't maintainable for when more conditions and callbacks will be added.

Components should be simple, readable and reusable while using all provided props as possible (i.e don't add unused props to component's logic):

```
const NOOP = () => {}
function CustomButton({ onClick = NOOP }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Cool Button</button>;
}
```

Better practice is to handle condition in parent's logic:

```
function Parent() {
  const onContinue = // ...
  const onStop = // ...
  return <CustomButton onClick={status ? onStop : onContinue} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better to pass a single callback `onClick` and handle the business logic inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `handleClick` inside `CustomButton` component before `return` and use if-else blocks to achieve this functionality. It is the right way, according to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom button and use it into any place with any props

```js
import React from 'react';

const CustomButton = ({ children, type = 'button', onClick }) => (
  <button
    type={type}
    onClick={onClick}
  >
    {children}
  </button>
);

const Parent = ({ status }) => {
  const stop = useCallback(() => {}, []);
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {}, []);
  
  return (
    status
      ? <CustomButton onClick={useCallback}>stop</CustomButton>
      : <CustomButton onClick={onClick}>click</CustomButton>
  );
}
```